# .htaccess redirect match to subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, subdirectory

I have the present structure now:
**www.site.com/reportddmmyyyy**

ex:
www.site.com/report01012015
www.site.com/report05012015

and I would like to move all the reports directory into a main directory: **reports**

**www.site.com/reports/reportddmmyyyy**

ex:
www.site.com/reports/report01012015
www.site.com/reports/report05012015

Many users have the old format in their bookmarks, so I need htaccess to detect that someone tried to access **www.site.com/reportddmmyyyy**
and show the content of **reports/reportddmmyyyy** without changing the browser URL.

Is it possible? I have been Googling for a long time but maybe I am not searching correctly. Could someone please point me in the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^report([^/]+)/?$ /reports/report$1 [NC,L]
```

This rule will rewrite

```
/report01011990
```

to

```
/reports/report01011990
```

without changing the url in your browser.

Comment: The URL is changing but it is a minor detail. The redirect works perfectly. Thank you